# How to use the oop in reading from mysql in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm trying to read from mysql with php and with oop.How can use from propeties?

This is my class and search function for reading from the database:

```
<?php
require_once('dbconfig.php');

class Film {

public $name;
public $year;
public $country;
public $director;
private $conn;

public function __construct() {
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->dbConnection();
    $this->conn = $db;
}

public function runQuery($sql) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql); 
    return $stmt;
}
public function search($name,$year,$country,$director) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where name='$name' or year='$year' or country='$country' or director='$director'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($num_rows > 0) {

            echo "</br>".$num_rows."&nbsp; film is found. </br>";
            echo "</br><table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Year</th><th>Country</th><th>durationMinutes</th><th>Director</th></tr>";

            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                 echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['year'] . "</td><td>" . $row['country'] . "</td><td>" . $row['durationMinutes'] . "</td><td>" . $row['director'] . "</td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "Nothing found !";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

I want search() is based on the object and properties.

How to change my code?

Comment: Can you give the title a facelift?

Comment: I have a list of movies and wanna the user can search by 'name' or 'country' or 'year' or ... .

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean you want to call that function?
just put this code wherever you wanna place it e.g in index.php.

```
$film->search($name,$year,$country,$director);
```

but you have to initial class film in your connection file like this

```
session_start();
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database="database";
try {
$con = new PDO ("mysql:host={$host}; dbname={$database}", $user, $pass);
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
}
catch (PDOEXception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
include_once 'class_film.php';
$film= new Film($con);
```

Comment: parameters in search($name,$year,$country,$director) are posted from client. I want to use from class properties e.g "public $name" .. .example for create connection, I use from $conn. generally I want to use object oriented.